# How to pass a variable from one component to another that is at the same level?

Tags: angular

How to pass a variable from one component to another that is at the same level? I have the user variable in the `Auth` component service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private user: string = null;

  getUser() {
    return this.user;
  }

  setUser(username) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('username', username);
    this.user = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
    console.log('VAMOS!!!', this.user);
  }
}
```

in the first component I inject it and if I get the value of the user variable then when the user authenticates I redirect it with `this.router.navigate (['/ meet'])` that is, I visualize the next component.

In this next component called list-user in which I get `null` in `getUser ()`.

```
async ngOnInit() {
  console.log('HOY', this.authService.getUser());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you redirect to ['/meet'], Authservice component is removed from DOM.

That's why it is providing null.

Why don't you use sessionStorage.getItem in your current component?

```
async ngOnInit() {

    console.log('HOY',sessionStorage.getItem('username'));
}
```

Comment: is safe use sessionStorage?

Comment: You have already used in Authservice  component. Then what is the problem with current component?.

Comment: Is there another way to visualize another view without refreshing the DOM?

Comment: Is there another way to manage sessions without using sessioStorage?

Comment: Till now I have no idea. Researching on it btw.

Comment: There are two more things for managing storage : localstorage and webstorage. 
You can do some research on them.

Answer (score 1):

We can use service store the data globally so that we can access the data in any component.

- If you provide the service in module level(same singleton instance
  will share for all component).
- If you provide  the service in component level(new instance will
  create for component).

So based on your use case do not inject the service in the component level.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'a-comp',
  template: `<div></div>`
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor( private authService: AuthService ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('HOY', this.authService.getUser());
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'b-comp',
  template: `<div></div>`
})
export class BComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor( private authService: AuthService ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('HOY', this.authService.getUser());
  }
}
```